# Create multiple elements

Tags: javascript, createelement

**JavaScript**

```
var textBlock = document.createElement('div');
textBlock.setAttribute('class', 'finalBlock');

var addFinalBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('block')[0];
addFinalBlock.appendChild(textBlock);

textBlock.innerHTML = "Make this block a text block";

// -------
var textBlock2 = document.createElement('div');
textBlock2.setAttribute('class', 'finalBlock');

var addFinalBlock2 = document.getElementsByClassName('block')[0];
addFinalBlock2.appendChild(textBlock2);

textBlock2.innerHTML = "Make this block a text block2";

// -------
var textBlock3 = document.createElement('div');
textBlock3.setAttribute('class', 'finalBlock');

var addFinalBlock3 = document.getElementsByClassName('block')[0];
addFinalBlock3.appendChild(textBlock3);

textBlock3.innerHTML = "Make this block a text block3";

// -------
var textBlock4 = document.createElement('div');
textBlock4.setAttribute('class', 'finalBlock');

var addFinalBlock4 = document.getElementsByClassName('block')[0];
addFinalBlock4.appendChild(textBlock4);

textBlock4.innerHTML = "Make this block a text block4";
```

I want to create 4 elements with different text. The class needs to remain the same. I think I am doing this with to much code.

Maybe anyone has some information how to make this code look more beautiful and more efficient?

Best wishes
and thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you do the **same things** a lot of times, use a **loop**. **Store** the different text in an **array** and go through it with **forEach**:

```
var text = ["text1", "tex2", "text3", "text4"];
text.forEach(function(el) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "finalBlock";
    div.innerHTML = el;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
});
```

or with a **for loop**:

```
var text = ["text1", "tex2", "text3", "text4"];
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i += 1) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "finalBlock";
    div.innerHTML = text[i];
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/83m4udv4/)

Answer (score 13):

I believe a better approach will be to only update the DOM once using `fragment`.

```
var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  docFrag.appendChild(divs[i]); // Note that this does NOT go to the DOM
} 
document.body.appendChild(docFrag); // Appends all divs at once
```

Answer (score 1):

**This code will work fine. If you want to add multiple elements on same HTML tag.**

```
            var element1=  "<br/>"
            var element2="<input type='text' />"
            var element3= "<br/>"
            var onLine = document.getElementById("onLine"); /* This is <ul id="onLine"></ul> */
            var on = document.createElement("div");

            on.innerHTML = element1+ element3+ element3

            on.setAttribute("style", "background-color:rgba(0, 0, 
            0, 0.3);color:white;border-radius:40px;margin- 
            bottom:30px;padding: 10px;width: 230px;");

            on.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Custom text'));

            onLine.appendChild(on);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. It is similar to [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) but you return the result.

```
const textblocks = ["textblock 1", "textblock 2", "textblock 3", "textblock 4"].map(text => {
    let div = document.createElement("div"); // p tag might be better suited for textblocks
    div.classList.add("finalBlock");
    div.textContent = text; // for text only, use textContent
    return div;
});
document.body.append(...textblocks); // append all in one function call
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a for loop to create multiple-element

```
let elementsCount = 3;
for (let i = 0; i < elementsCount; i++) {
     const element = document.createElement('div');
     document.body.appendChild(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is parent child relationship, most efficient way to insert multiple elements is using text as template:

```js
const el = document.createElement('div');

el.innerHTML = `
<div class="final-block">Block One</div>
<div class="final-block">Block Two</div>
<div class="final-block">Block Three</div>
<div class="final-block">Block Four</div>
`;

// Then insert wherever you want
document.querySelector('#app').appendChild(el);
```

This is faster than iteration and easier to understand.

If you need to generate those children from an array:

```js
const el = document.createElement('ul');
el.innerHTML = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'].reduce((a, c) => a + `<li>${c}</li>`, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured I would show another option just for anyone looking at this.
The difference from other options is making use of map(),cloneNode(), textContent (instead of innerHTML), and the spread operator to append the array of nodes to the block div.

```
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    const blockData = [
        {
            "blockclass":"finalBlock",
            "text":"text1"
        },
        {
            "blockclass":"finalBlock",
            "text":"text2"
        },
        {
            "blockclass":"finalBlock",
            "text":"text3"
        },
        {
            "blockclass":"finalBlock",
            "text":"text4"
        }
    ];
    let blockdiv;
    const textBlocks = blockData.map(obj => {
        blockdiv = div.cloneNode(false);
        blockdiv.className = obj.blockclass;
        blockdiv.textContent = obj.text;
        return blockdiv;
    });

document.querySelector(".block").append(...textBlocks);
```