# Add select dropdown to table column with JS

Tags: javascript

I have created a table in HTML (4 rows and 3 columns). But I want to add a select dropdown in the second column. I am unable to add that in the column.

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Criteria</th>
    <th>Yes/No</th> 
    <th>Comments</th>
  </tr>
<script>

var array1 = [1,2,3,4];
for(var i=0; i<array1.length; i++)
{ 

document.write("<tr>");

document.write("<td>"+array1[i]+"</td>");
document.write("<td>  </td>");
document.write("<td>  </td>");

document.write("</tr>");


}
</script>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And the select dropdown HTML is:

```
<select name="mydropdown">
    <option value="Milk">Fresh Milk</option>
    <option value="Cheese">Old Cheese</option>
    <option value="Bread">Hot Bread</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you tell us how you want the final table?

Comment: Why is your script tag inside the table?

Comment: This question was asked 1 year, 4 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Criteria</th>
      <th>Yes/No</th>
      <th>Comments</th>
    </tr>
    <script>
      var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
      for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {

        var dropdown = "<select name='mydropdown'>" +
          "<option value='Milk'>Yes</option>" +
          "<option value='Cheese'>No</option>" +
          "</select>";

        document.write("<tr>");

        document.write("<td>" + array1[i] + "</td>");
        document.write("<td>" + dropdown + "</td>");
        document.write("<td>  </td>");

        document.write("</tr>");


      }
    </script>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think nowadays you should not `document.write` but use HTML DOM instead, more like https://stackoverflow.com/a/32671045/111995